# Select multi condition on parameter with Rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I want to retrieve all User or get all User with Name variable. I'm using Rethinkdb and I want to convert SQL Server to Rethinkdb with my query

SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM User
WHERE Name = '' OR Name = @ Name
```

This 's my Rethinkdb query, but It not working right

```
rethink.table('User')
.filter(
rethink.row('Name').eq(Name).or(rethink.row('Name'))
)
.run(conn, callback)
```

Comment: Can you try modifying your filter to: rethink.row('Name').eq(Name).or(rethink.row('Name').eq(''))

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
r.table('User').filter(function(d){
    return r.expr([Name, ""]).contains(d('Name'))
})
```